# Wordpress: wrong subcategory slug

Tags: wordpress

Recently I started using sub-category on my Wordpress blog and I discovered a strange thing.
If i create a subcategory "kitchen" with slug "kitchen" when I save it, I see that slug has been changed in "home-kitchen" where home is the parent category.
I don't understand why, I'm using last wordpress version and I shouldn't have plugin that change it.

Someone know how can i fix it?

Comment: Do you have another category/sub category called kitchen anywhere else?

Comment: No, i can change the subcategory name with something else random and it alsways change the slug in that way. It's really strange...